# Can I add sent mailing to a campaign

Tags: civimail, civicampaign

The NGO I'm working with decided to create campaigns for all the ongoing projects. We weren't using this information previously, so I wasn't tagging the mailings to a project but now retroactively some of the mailings belong to some of the campaigns. Is there any way that I can edit the sent mailing and use campaign information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

campaign_id is a field in the civicrm_mailing table in your database. I suspect that the only ways to modify this are
- edit the db directly
- use the API Explorer to change the value assuming this is available via the UI (via /civicrm/api#explorer)

hopefully those are enough pointers for a start

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I couldn't find in API explorer (in neither of the versions) mailing table to update. I understand that I can make it thru mysql and that's fine for me at the moment. Thank you.

Comment: sorry I had not checked to see if it was available so tweaked my msg